# Creating text boxes for swagger requestBody to populate it?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am trying to write an api documentation using swagger. My use case is, I have all post services with application/xml as request content-type. I was able to get the xml tp requestBody from openapi spec file. But it is a very large xml and it is getting very messy to edit the requestBody and hit the api. I was looking if there is a way where I can populate the requestBody attributes with any text boxes [ like i enter the text for that attribute and it populates it to the requestBody]. Any ideas on customizing swagger are highly helpful.